# React useContext returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to use React Context to manage states for my project, but I can't seem to make it work for my CRA codebase this time while I had successful attempts on other projects. `useContext` returns undefined so I couldn't access the values inside the context, but I have double checked that my Provider is at my app root level. Appreciate any help.

This is my simplified App component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import { PlayerContextProvider, PlayerContext } from 'contexts/PlayerContext';

const App = () => (
  <PlayerContextProvider>
    <Test />
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </PlayerContextProvider>
);

const Test = () => {
  const values = useContext(PlayerContext);
  console.log('test values', values); // returns undefined!

  return <div>Hello World</div>;
};

export default App;
```

This is my context:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';

const PlayerContext = createContext();

const PlayerContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(['test']);

  const addPlayer = ({ name }) => {
    setPlayers([...players, { name }]);
  };

  const values = { players, addPlayer };
  console.log('context values', players); // shows ['test'] here

  return (
    <PlayerContext.Provider values={values}>
      <>
        {players}
        {children}
      </>
    </PlayerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { PlayerContextProvider, PlayerContext };
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a small typo.

Instead of `values` the correct is `value` without `s`.

```
<PlayerContext.Provider value={values}>
```

## Edit:

If you are getting `undefined` and isn't because of the typo, you probably forgot to "wrap" a component with the `Provider` and the `undefined` value comes from the first argument of `React.createContext()` (which is undefined is you don't pass anything)

Comment: Wow.. I was looking at the code for 5 minutes and just couldn't see it. Now I can't unsee it 

Comment: This had me scratching my (wondering what I was doing wrong) for about 30minutes!